# Is there an alternate option for repairing registry items left as not fixed by sfc /scannow?

Tags: windows-7

My PC is running Windows 7 64Bit and, since I've had to replace the (OEM) HDD, both Win Update & Win Troubleshooters are not working. The only OS Media DVD's I have are the OEM (Acer) recovery discs. I did the full recovery procedure and then, I had to restore PC functionality via WinOOBE (Windows refused to start after recovery) but still have the problems and the sfc /scannow reports that there are issues still not fixed. I think something (factory installed) might be left along with the damaged OEM HDD but I don't know what else to do. May someone be of help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it still under warranty? Boot and install Win7 from an untouched ISO (after backing up your important files of course and wiping the disk clean) and activate using your key. As a bonus you'll be free of OEM bloatware and crapware.

Comment: Hi Karan; Thanks for your prompt comment. The PC is not under warranty. Regarding the ISO; Do you refer to an image from the present OS files? I ask because, if you refer to a previous system image, I think it may not be possible to obtain because, as I said before, the original OEM HDD failed and is now useless, thus, the present OS comes from the OEM recovery disk set. Again; ...Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: No, I meant a Windows Setup ISO. Used to be available from Digital River but now only retail users can get it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery) with OEM users unfortunately being left out. You'll have to source it from elsewhere but just ensure the SHA1 hashes match those on MSDN ([for example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads#searchTerm=Windows%207%20Home%20Premium%20with%20Service%20Pack%201)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, the [Microsoft System Readiness Update Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947821) that in my case has repaired what sfc couldn't even detect.

Microsoft describes the Readiness tool as pre-req for upgrading to 8 by detecting and fixing problems without actually launching any OS upgrade.

The Readiness Update is what I run in lieu of SFC that seems overprescribed at the Microsoft Forums before they predictably instruct the uninitiated to carpetbomb their installation with a Reset.

Comment: Hello Sam Punctual; Thanks a lot for your willingness to help but, unfortunately, the MSRU refused to configure in the system when I intended to use it. I think that having critical functions like Windows Update, Troubleshooters and Installers unusable, is what worsens things in my case. Any further comment is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Well, carpet-bombing it may be, but I've found the All in One fixer from tweaking.com to be very effective - http://www.tweaking.com/content/overview/default.html